# Is it safe to put error handling in the end event of a Node http request stream?

Tags: node.js

Looking to log an error and reject a request if a node request stream returns any statusCode other than 200 range, but I want to get the response from the request if available even if it fails because it sometimes has useful information on failure cause. So my question is if I put my check for statusCode inside the end event, is there a possibility it will never be called and the program will hang? Is there a better way to get the response body and reject on statusCode?

```
const request = http.get(url, (response) => {
            const body = [];
            response.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk));
            response.on('end', () => {
                // handle http errors
                if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
                    reject(new ErrorClass(response.statusCode, body.join('')));
                } else {
                    resolve(body.join(''))
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `response` passed to the callback is a [Readable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable).

The Node.js doc says this about the `end` event:

> The 'end' event is emitted when there is no more data to be consumed
>   from the stream.
>
> Note: The 'end' event will not be emitted unless the data is
>   completely consumed. This can be accomplished by switching the stream
>   into flowing mode, or by calling stream.read() repeatedly until all
>   data has been consumed.

It says this about the `data` event:

> Attaching a 'data' event listener to a stream that has not been
>   explicitly paused will switch the stream into flowing mode. Data will
>   then be passed as soon as it is available.

And it says this about the `error` event that can be emitted by the request object returned by `http.request` (of which `http.get` is a special case):

> If any error is encountered during the request (be that with DNS
>   resolution, TCP level errors, or actual HTTP parse errors) an 'error'
>   event is emitted on the returned request object. As with all 'error'
>   events, if no listeners are registered the error will be thrown.

Since your code attaches a `data` event listener and consumes all chunks, the `end` data listener will be called after there is no more data to be consumed -- *unless* the `error` event is emitted (usually due to some underlying issue that prevents completion of response processing). Therefore, you code should also listen for the `error` event. For example:

```
const request = http.get(url, (response) => {
  const body = [];
  response.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk));
  response.on('end', () => {
    // handle http errors
    if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
        reject(new ErrorClass(response.statusCode, body.join('')));
    } else {
        resolve(body.join(''))
    }
  });
});
request.on('error', (e) => {
  reject(e);
});
```

Comment: Good answer. But, I believe the error handling should be on `http.get()`, like this `http.get(...).on('error', (e) => { reject(e); });`.  Like in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback).  Having the error handling where you have it would potentially cause unhandled errors.

Comment: Sounds like as long as I handle the end and error events, my code won't fail silently. Great answer, thanks.